# Estimating forecasting error in multi-step process

Tags: forecasting, error, sensitivity-analysis

Suppose a process which looks something like this

> time series 1 --> model 1 --> time series 2 --> model 2 --> time
> series 3

An initial time series, which is a forecast, is used as input in the first model, which generates a second time series, also a forecast. This is then fed into a second model, which generates yet another forecast. Note: the actual process is more messy than this, with a lot more time series and models. Also, the models are complex and non-linear.

After some time I obtain the actual values for each of these 3 time series. I would now like to evaluate the forecasting error which belong to each component in the process, that is the error which belongs to the data (because the forecasts were imperfect) or the error which belongs to the models (because the models were imperfect).

My idea is as follows: after I obtain all the actual values I use the actual series in the process above, this will give me the "best" forecasts possible. All the error which is obtained with this data belongs to the models. Then I sequentially swap each actual series with its forecast counterpart and run the whole process again. Any accumulated additional error belongs to the data.

Is this approach correct? Are there other more appropriate methods to achieve this?